# Extracting redirected link from an url

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to extract the redirected link of [this link](https://www.forexfactory.com/news/403059-manufacturing-in-us-expands-after-reaching-three-year-low/hit). When I click on this link I am redirected to [this page](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2013-01-02/ism-index-of-u-s-manufacturing-increased-to-50-7-in-december) and I want to store this page link. So, for this I have tried with urllib module but it didn't give any response.

```
from urllib import request
headers = headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'}
url = 'https://www.forexfactory.com/news/403059-manufacturing-in-us-expands-after-reaching-three-year-low/hit'
 
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response)  #  Output: <Response [503]>
```

So, how can I extract this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cloudscraper](https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper) to process the cloudflare redirect:

```
import cloudscraper
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
url = 'https://www.forexfactory.com/news/403059-manufacturing-in-us-expands-after-reaching-three-year-low/hit'
r = scraper.get(url)
print(r.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library

```
import requests

headers  = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'}
url = 'https://www.forexfactory.com/news/403059-manufacturing-in-us-expands-after-reaching-three-year-low/hit'

 
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.url)
```